# Prevent ScrollView from Scrolling on Certain TextViews, Enable Scrolling on Specific TextView within Nested Hierarchy in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 3 textviews nested inside a scroll view. Everytime I press inside the first textview the page scrolls up like it should. However, I want to prevent the scrolling for the first 2 text views but allow it for the third.

i tried but the problem still exists need solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.